# Prepending Default Value in Rails Select Form Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running into an error when trying to add a default value to my form helper select dropdown. What am I doing wrong?

```
<%= f.select :type_page_id, @type_pages.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id],["Pagina Principal",0]},} %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now what you mean. There are a lot of way for you to accomplish this sort of thing, no doubt. My favorite way is to do this in the controller:

```
@type_pages = TypePage.all.collect do |type_page|
   [type_page.name, type_page.id]
end.unshift(['Pagina Principal', 0])
```

Then when you're in the form helper in your `html.erb` you can use:

```
<%= f.select :type_page_id, @type_pages %>
```

Comment: **I need to add a value that is not in my database something like this, but I get error sintaxys:** `{|t| [t.name,t.id],["Pagina Principal",0]}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to make `Pagina Principal` the default selection from `@type_pages` names

```
<%= f.select :type_page_id, @type_pages.map(&:name), selected: "Pagina Principal" %>
```